# Ant Design Table is not updated immediately when switching checkbox and reload content

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

Help friends find a bug.

There is a **table**, data is loaded from the backend, there is a `boolean variable` in the data, which is displayed in the table by the `checkbox`. When the `checkbox` is changed, the function changes the state of a variable in the `database` and reloads the data. But the table is redrawn only for the 2nd time. In accordance with this, the `checkbox` and record styles are not updated after the function has been executed.

Point out where to look?

```
class UsersList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            isLoading: false
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    loadUsersList() {
        let promise = getAllUsers();

        this.setState({
                isLoading: true
            }
        );

        if (!promise) {
            return;
        }

        promise
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    users: response,
                    isLoading: false
                })
            }).catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false
            })
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadUsersList();
    }

    onChange(e) {
        setEnabled(e.target.value, e.target.checked).then(this.loadUsersList());

        notification.success({
            message: 'Successfully',
            description: "Enabled field of " + e.target.value + " change to " + e.target.checked,
        });
    }

    render() {

        const columns = [{
            title: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            key: 'id'
        }, {
            title: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            key: 'name'
        }, {
            title: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            key: 'email'
        }, {
            title: 'Registered',
            dataIndex: 'registered',
            key: 'registered'
        }, {
            title: 'Enabled',
            dataIndex: 'enabled',
            key: 'enabled',
            render: (text, record) => (
                <Checkbox checked={record.enabled}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          value={record.name}/>
            )
        }, {
            title: 'Roles',
            dataIndex: 'roles',
            key: 'roles'
        }
           ];

        return (
            <Table rowClassName={(row) => row.enabled ? '' : 'disabled'}
                   rowKey='id' columns={columns}
                   dataSource={this.state.users}
                   loading={this.state.isLoading}/>
        )
    }
}

export default UsersList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the best solution here but since you are using a columns array and not explicitly specify columns under , then you might as well put it in a method that updates when the user interacts with your UI

use this to access the column tag within table, put it outside your class

`const { Column, ColumnGroup } = Table;`